# SQL multiple query using with - in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, with-statement

I'm trying to figure out how to make a single request including several queries in order to generate one view including all my queries results.

Here the example :

```
WITH Query_1 AS
(
SELECT
dimension1,
dimension2,
dimension3,
dimension4,
dimension5,

CASE WHEN STARTS_WITH (dimension1, "N_") THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS qadimension1,
CASE WHEN dimension2 IS NOT NULL THEN dimension2 ELSE '0' END AS qadimension2,
CASE WHEN dimension3 IS NOT NULL THEN dimension3 ELSE '0' END AS qadimension3,
CASE WHEN dimension4 IS NOT NULL THEN dimension4 ELSE '0' END AS qadimension4,
FROM `XXXXX.XXXXX.first_view`
WHERE dimension5='2021' AND dimension1 IS NOT NULL),

Query_2 AS (
SELECT
dimension1,
qadimension1,
dimension6,

CASE WHEN qadimension1 = dimension6 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS QA_check1,
FROM `XXXXX.XXXXX.first_view` , `XXXXX.XXXXX.second_view`
WHERE qadimension1 != '0'),


Query_3 AS (
SELECT
dimension1,
qadimension2,
dimension7,

CASE WHEN qadimension2 = dimension7 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS QA_check2,
FROM `XXXXX.XXXXX.first_view` , `XXXXX.XXXXX.third_view`
WHERE qadimension2 != '0')



SELECT 
dimension1,
dimension2,
dimension3,
dimension4,
dimension5,
dimension6,
dimension7,

qadimension1,
qadimension2,
qadimension3,
qadimension4,

QA_check1,
QA_check2,

FROM
Query_1,
Query_2,
Query_3

WHERE FULL JOIN dimension1;
```

still have an error : Syntax error: Unexpected keyword FULL at [242:7]

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Hi Gordon, in fact, i have errors when i'm trying to run at the same time CASE statements. So i separate in multiple queries. I'm trying to run each queries and the result i would like is a view or table with all my dimensions (column with reuslts) using as a key the dimension1. Let me know if it's still unclear. Thanks for your help - david

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Try below - note no changes for all CTEs, so below just final select statement

```
SELECT 
  dimension1,
  dimension2,
  dimension3,
  dimension4,
  dimension5,
  dimension6,
  dimension7,

  q2.qadimension1,
  q3.qadimension2,
  qadimension3,
  qadimension4,

  QA_check1,
  QA_check2

FROM Query_1
LEFT JOIN Query_2 q2 USING(dimension1)
LEFT JOIN Query_3 q3 USING(dimension1)
```

Comment: Hi Mikhail, thanks for your help. I had this error message : "Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many fields accessed or query is too complex." I really don't know why it's not working as i split queries in order to be able to run multiple requests.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's not better to use UNION ALL to run this kind of job. The objective i'm seeking is to run multiple request and get as final result a view or table with all my dimensions 5columns) containing results of my request. My key will be dimension 1 for example.

Comment: I think the issue is in your views. Have you tried to run your views separatelly? Also try to materialize your CTEs as tables or materialized views before executing final join. As of union - based on what I see in your question - Union is not what will give you expected result!

Comment: Hi Mikhail, many thanks for your feedback, could you just give me more details, i'm really stuck - thanks david